# Find and replace string from XML file using talend DI

Tags: xml, talend

My XML Files have a DOCTYPE tag that prevents me from using a tFileInputXML. Hence I want to find and replace the below string in Talend Job? Using Talend 5.4 Free version.

```
**<!DOCTYPE log
[
    <!ENTITY % log SYSTEM "xxxx_1.0.dtd" >
    <!ENTITY % detail SYSTEM "yyyy_log_1.0.dtd" >
    %log;
    %detail;
]>**
```

If I use a tFileInputXML to read this file without replacing I am not able to parse the content within the XML.  I am thinking I should either be able to do a tFileInputRegex and find and replace and then process the file through tFileInputXML?

Answer (score 0):

The tFileInputRegex component is designed to define the structure of a text document so you can extract columns from the document so wouldn't be of use here.

I see a couple of options available to you here:

If your header takes up a predefined set amount of rows you could use a tFileInputFullRow component and set the header to be the amount of rows of the header. You could then output this as an XML file and read it back in with a tFileInputXML.

If your header isn't a set amount of rows but is able to be extracted by a regex pattern then you could input the file once again into a tFileInputFullRow and set the row separator to `""` to read the whole thing in as a single line. From here you could use a tExtractRegexFields using something like `^\\*\\*<!DOCTYPE log.+?]>\\*\\*(.+)$` to extract everything other than your header. Be warned that this doesn't actually quite work because it would need single line mode to be active (you'll have a bunch of newline characters in there that the `.` won't match) and I don't see a way of setting a regex mode in the component. As a precursor you could maybe try removing all the new line characters in the string.